# How do I wildcard all directories that are tracked by git?

Tags: git, wildcard

I want to track a directory using git which contains other directories already tracked by git. I would like to exclude those already tracked directories.

I would like to do this with one simple wildcard instead of adding them manually and tried `**/.git`, but this seems to point to all entries in all the *.git* directories, which is not what I want.

How do I get all directories that contain a subdirectory named *.git* using wildcards? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard meaning "any directory containing an entry with this name".  You'll need exclusion rules for each existing repo.

You could use something like `find . -name .git |sed s/[^\/]*$//` to generate the rules

Comment: Do I run this command in the directory and copy the results or can I put it directly into the .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

You're treading into `git submodule` territory.  Git commits cannot contain a `.git` pathname or component (this is forbidden for security reasons) and any attempt to add some directory that *contains* a `.git` will be treated as an attempt to add a submodule instead.

If you *do* want submodules, use `git submodule add` to add them *correctly;* `git add` alone will not do that.  If you *don't* want submodules, watch out here.

Note too that Git tracks only *files*, not directories.  Files in Git have slashes in their names, such as `src/a.js`.  That is not a directory named `src` holding a file named `a.js`, it's just a *file* named `src/a.js`.

It's not clear to me whether you're trying to build a `.gitignore` to *ignore* all the things that Git would turn into submodules.  If so, use [Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917927/1256452) to find the list of such path names.

It's also possible to let `git add .` do its thing, including adding submodules that are missing `.gitmodules` data, then "back out" the submodules using `git ls-files --stage` to find mode `160000` entries (gitlinks) and remove them from the index with `git rm --cached`, but this assumes that you don't have any legitimate submodules that you would like to keep.